# should tcp/udp data field be converted to network byte order

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

if machine A and machine B are communicating with each other, but they are with different host byte order
then in network-programming,on the sending side, should tcp/udp data field be converted to network byte order
why?
thanks!

Comment: The question is probably a better choice for Programmers.SE, as it's subjective. That said, I'll give you a subjective answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're following a pre-existing specification, it will be safest to always use [network byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking) (aka "big-endian"):

- You need to specify *some* byte order; you can't just send binary data and hope that the receiver can figure it out.
- Because big-endian data is a [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700) of the Internet, there are lots of tools to convert to/from *host* byte order. You'd have to write your own tools to convert between host and little-endian.

The traditional argument against is "all the world's a VAX" (or today, x86), which is little-endian, and so network byte order imposes a performance tax on data. Perhaps that was a valid argument 20 or 30 years ago, but it certainly isn't today. The amount of time that your processor takes to convert data is an infinitesimal fraction of the time it takes to move that data across the network.

Comment: +1 for explaining performance implication argument and counter-argument

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly recommended in many cases. To explain the reason why, let's look at an example:

1. You have a program that takes a 32-bit unsigned int, places it in a packet and sends to another host
2. The other host pulls the data out of the packet and stores it as a 32-bit unsigned int.
3. Sending host is big endian, receiving host is little endian.

If the sending host in the above example sends the number 1024, that number is stored on the sending host's machine as 0x00000400. If the receiving host doesn't change the byte order when receiving those bytes and stores 0x00000400 in memory, this will be interpreted as a totally different number than 1024. The little-endian representation of the decimal number 1024 would be 0x00040000. On a little-endian machine, 0x00000400 is the decimal number 262,144.

Converting to network-byte order allows the programs to rely on a standard encoding of the data to avoid confusion like we see in the above example. Functions on the receiver side to convert from network-byte order to whatever byte-order it uses are easily available and simple to use.

Answer (score -3):

**TCP** has built-in mechanisms for re-ordering received packets. **UDP** hasn't. I'm not sure what do you mean by "different host byte order", but it the packets are received with byte-level errors then that's the layer 2 role to retransmit such a packets.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Doesn't even appear to understand it.

Comment: @EJP: Do you understand the question? I don't, but tried to be as much helpful as possible. If you already know the answer why don't you share it?

Comment: You're confused between ordering of packets and order of bytes within a packet. TCP has mechanisms to re-order packets on the receiver side if they are received in a different order than the order in which they were sent. The OP is talking about the issue of byte-ordering within packets (see little-endian vs. big-endian: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: @Guardian Your answer and comment exhibit several fallacies. It is possible to understand a question without knowing an answer; it is possible to know an answer without posting it here; and it is also impossible to answer a question without understanding it.